# Issues with UEFI: Can't save settings and can't boot OS automatically

Tags: boot, ssd, bios

**Product**: HP r245tx (mohterboard system board ID 2337)

- Specs: Insyde UEFI F.36, 250GB SSD, 8GB RAM, running Windows 10 x64

I've installed Windows 10 x64 on my laptop. Here are the issues which I'm facing:

1. The boot-up is long, however restarting is way fast
2. UEFI doesn't boot directly Windows, it keeps saying no bootable device found; 
    I'm booting my laptop manually by using the boot device selection, and then opening the appropriate EFI file, here `bootx64.efi`
3. UEFI settings aren't getting saved, and even though I select "Exit with saving changes", the settings aren't sustained on the next boot up.
4. HP splash screen doesn't appear at boot up.

On seeing these issues, I thought something was wrong with the UEFI firmware, so I downloaded the latest official UEFI driver (F.46, Rev A), but it couldn't update the UEFI firmware; upon further inspection, I found the driver didn't contain a UEFI firmware image for my motherboard and I have been unable to find that anywhere.

Are there any other ways to go about solving this problem?

#### Update

I forgot to mention that even though I have 8 GB RAM on my PC, the system information shows it to be 4 GB sometimes.

#### Update 2:

I have opened up my laptop. The motherboard number is ASO56 - LA - B972P.
Please help me with how to trace back the BIOS that should be compatible with this board. I suspect that during a past repair at the HP service centre, they probably mixed up things a bit.

#### Solved *******************************

Th problem wasn't with the BIOS. It was due to bug in the Kubuntu Linux kernel that I was trying to install. Fixed it following instructions in this link.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147%C2%A0

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question, but BIOS or UEFI firmware updates should be downloaded directly from the OEM's [HP] support page for your machine (or motherboard if bought independently), as UEFI firmware must be signed by the OEM. Just an FYI, BIOS and UEFI are not the same things and if you're booting via EFI, you have a UEFI motherboard. If @Keltari's answer works, but the slow boot-ups persists, CSM [legacy mode] needs to be disabled _(if you installed Windows with CSM enabled, you'll likely need to reinstall Windows)_

Comment: I downloaded the firmware from HP itself, but weirdly it doesn't provide the proper firmware, as mentioned in the question. Since then I've been trying to find the proper image online but to no avail. Also, I'd like to add one more thing, I downloaded F.36, which is currently the firmware on my machine, but weirdly enough, it didn't have an image for my board(2337) even though it is the stock board.

Comment: You used [this](https://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp93001-93500/sp93115.exe) file from the [Software and drivers for HP Notebook - 15-r245tx](https://support.hp.com/in-en/drivers/selfservice/HP-15-Notebook-PC-series/7486447/model/8525066) page?  If so, you need to contact HP.

Comment: I already contacted them, but they said that since my laptop is out of warranty, they won't provide me support and asked to me to reach out to their forums. I've posted a question in their forums but I don't have much hope.

Comment: Specific to my prior comment, if you downloaded the linked to UEFI update _(please verify that is what you downloaded and received an error on)_, and it's erroring out, tech support should troubleshoot that specifically, as that's HP's own software and is not related to your hardware. Specific to my comment under @Keltari's answer, if the CMOS battery was installed w/ correct side touching the contact, you're likely going to need some form of professional tech support, as that's indicative of a failed BIOS/UEFI chip _(not certain how likely that is but I have experienced it on a server board)_

Comment: _Cont'd..._ If it is a failed UEFI/BIOS chip, they can be replaced by an electronics repair company that has a microscope soldering station, such as [UBreakIFix](https://www.ubreakifix.com/). I am **_not_** stating that is the issue, as it's generally a diagnosis of exclusion, but if it is, you'll want to cost compare HP's cost to fix vs a professional 3rd party _(HP will likely replace the motherboard versus paying for an hour's worth of labor to replace the chip)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't with the BIOS. It was due to bug in the Kubuntu Linux kernel that I was trying to install. Fixed it following instructions in this link.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147%C2%A0

Answer (score 1):

The symptoms point the internal [CMOS battery](https://www.yourdictionary.com/cmos-battery) being dead.  The CMOS battery saves the desktop's/laptop's BIOS settings when the computer is not being powered by either the power adapter or the laptop battery.  When this battery is no longer able to keep those settings active, the settings are lost and need to be reset each boot.  Sometimes this results in the device trying to boot a drive other than the one the operating systems is on.  Additionally, the clock in the computer is off, but this can be often missed, as most operating systems check the internet and automatically set the proper time.  What is odd, is that it is common for the computer to post a warning at boot that the battery is not working.  It is possible that you missed the warning or it isnt being shown for some reason.

I would open up the laptop and check the CMOS battery with a multimeter, and/or replace it.  They are very cheap.  If this turns out not to be the issue, then I would seek further help.

Comment: Actually, I myself had the same doubt so I replaced the battery yesterday itself, but as is evident, the issue still persists. I also opened the "System Log" in the bios to look for error codes, but there was only one "000a" which is for initialising the keyboard.

Comment: @DevankMishra Did you verify the CMOS battery was installed with the correct side touching the contact? If so, contact HP.

Comment: Yes, I verified. The battery was placed correctly.